# 1 more vote from other users is needed to delete this post?

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-delete

Since I recently reached 10K reputation, I'm itching to delete questions. BWAHAHAHAHAH!

Well, actually, no. But still, I've found something curious when voting to delete. I see a question in the Delete and Undelete Votes -> Most Votes. I go to the question, and the tooltip on the delete button says:

> 1 more vote is needed to delete this post

So I agree that it's a good fit for deletion, and I click on delete annnnnndddd... the tooltip changes to:

> You voted to delete. 1 more vote from other users is needed to delete this post

That's very anticlimactic.

So, is the first tooltip incorrect? Is the second tooltip incorrect? Wasn't my vote counted? Does it receive a lower weight for some reason? Or are questions deleted later, either in batch or after some kind of review process?

Comment: BTW, my bet is on option #1. All the questions I've browsed seem to say "1 more vote is needed".

Comment: The [number of delete votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/182513) need to delete is related to the popularity of the post.  It is possible that the the post received upvotes and the threshold needed to delete changed while you were in the process of voting?

Comment: @psubsee2003 It _might_ be possible, but I doubt it. Happened 4 times already.

Comment: I'm looking at the mod tools on MSE and everything seems correct.  the mod tools are showing the appropriate number of delete votes needed and when I go to the question, and cast a vote, the post gets deleted.  Either is isolated to SO, or there is another issue here.

Comment: I'm 99% sure I've seen a bug report about this on MSE (and a bug report on MSO in the past day or two before it was removed by its asker)... But I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I can confirm the same issue.  *every* post that I can cast a delete vote on says '1 more needed'.  Even ones with just one vote.  (Also, the vote count on the Review page is wrong by a significant amount on some of them, unless it's really slow at caching?)

Comment: Ah ha! Found something. Related: [Mouseover tooltip for delete count is wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233537/mouseover-tooltip-for-delete-count-is-wrong). Maybe [Confusion about how many votes are needed to undelete a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233807/confusion-about-how-many-votes-are-needed-to-undelete-a-post) too?

Comment: Yep, that's what I found also.

Comment: @user3580294 Well, sorry for the duplication folks. I didn't find it when I searched. I'll just enjoy my new deleting powers on my own post! :)

Comment: Rather odd that the other post was closed as a duplicate of the one, and yet they didn't answer or do anything about the one?

Comment: @matiash No problem! Had to some digging with google searches, and probably had an "advantage" in that I was pretty certain that it existed, so it's understandable. Might be nice to have an update though...

Comment: @matiash No need to delete it, honestly; good to keep this here as a link to the MSE post (so others don't post same Q here).

Comment: this should have been a MSE question not an MSO question. I have [asked one yesterday](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265166/got-tricked-with-1-more-vote-is-needed-to-delete-this-question) but deleted it because there already is a [request for this on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233537/mouseover-tooltip-for-delete-count-is-wrong)

Comment: @mehow: The guidelines after the MSE and MSO split are that any question can be posted to MSO. If it is common to all sites, mods will migrate.

Comment: Well but it applies to the entire SE network not only SO so IMO the right home for this question would be MSE.

Comment: Awww, I had my torch and pitchfork all ready to go and there's not even a specific question to h̶u̶n̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶e̶n̶d̶s̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶E̶a̶r̶t̶h̶ delete.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Haha, no, it was just a general bug report. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was due to a very small logic error in our code. I have patched it up and you'll see it live in the next release! (Meta: > rev `2014.7.11.2366`, Sites: > rev `2014.7.11.1701`)

Comment: MUHAHAHAHA! Now I know how many evil companions I have :D

Comment: And in the end, isn't that what matters @Braiam?